# Simple SQL Server issue with formatting dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a month from a date returned as a full month name. For example, I'm using

```
SELECT FORMAT(MONTH(GETDATE()),xxxxxx)
```

I don't know what to make `xxxxxx` in order to get it to return as "November".

Is this even possible, or is it something that I can't get it to do?

EDIT: Never mind. I noticed that the error I'm getting doesn't even reference the `xxxxxx` part. It tells me "FORMAT" is not a regonized built-in function name.

Comment: `FORMAT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server 2012 and not available in earlier versions of SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATENAME`.

```
SELECT datename(month, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi @phroureo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: I tried clicking it, and it told me to wait 13 minutes. That passed ~6 minutes after your comment.